# Error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'auth_type'" during the installation of Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I am trying to install Apache Superset on Windows Server based on: https://apache.github.io/superset/installation.html, But after execute: `fabmanager create-admin --app superset`
I got the error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py",
> line 197, in _run_module_as_main
>
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
>
> exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\fabmanager.exe_*main*_.py",
> line 7, in
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\console.py",
> line 422, in cli
>
> cli_app()
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1130, in **call**
>
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1055, in main
>
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1657, in invoke
>
> return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1404, in invoke
>
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 760, in invoke
>
> return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\console.py",
> line 137, in create_admin
>
> auth_type.get(_appbuilder.sm.auth_type, "No Auth method")
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'auth_type'

How can I fix this issue?